# Django 1.5.4 error_messages in ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform, form-fields, neo4django

I have a very simple ModelForm subclass:

```
class UserPrefsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username']
```

When I try to save the form in my view (only the post function here):

```
def post(self, request):
    userform =  UserPrefsForm(request.POST)
    context = self.get_context_data()
    if userform.is_valid():
        userform.save()
    else:
        context['errors'] = True
    return render(request,self.template_name,context)
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError at /prefs
'super' object has no attribute 'error_messages'
Traceback:
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/braces/views.py" in dispatch
  107.             request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tonjo/prj/tuned_prj/tuned_django/graph/views.py" in post
  147.         if userform.is_valid():
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  126.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  117.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  274.         self._post_clean()
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  344.             self.validate_unique()
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in validate_unique
  353.             self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in validate_unique
  731.         errors = self._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _perform_unique_checks
  831.                 errors.setdefault(key, []).append(self.unique_error_message(model_class, unique_check))
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in unique_error_message
  882.             return field.error_messages['unique'] % {
File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/src/neo4django/neo4django/utils.py" in __getattr__
  303.         return getattr(target, name)
```

I understand is the missing `error_messages`... Am I forced to define them?

Comment: are you using a custom field?

Comment: It may not help, but can we see the User model?

Comment: @lalo, all the form fields are shown, and I'm using `neo4django`'s own model fields.

Comment: The problem seems to be neo4django's `StringProperty()` model fields.